# Split population number by area

Tags: arcmap, intersection, overlay, analysis

So, I have a polygon that contains the population number. Another polygon is a zone polygon.

I need to approximate population from the first polygon to zones polygon, but based on intersection percent.

[image]

Here is an example. Purple polygon contains population data. Now, how to split for example population of 64 to other polygons based on the percent of their intersection.

I tried to use ratio policy on a polygon with population data, then clip it with other polygon, but with no luck.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Clip the population polygons with the yellow layer
2. Make Feature layer on clip output with `Use ratio policy` on value field:
   [image]
3. Intersect the created layer and your yellow polygons

Comment: Is this maybe possible to do in R?

Comment: I'm sure it is. You should post it as a new question